# how to divide and insert post value integer data in mysql two column using php?

Tags: mysql, php

```
   <form>
    Service fee :
   <input type="text" value="300" name="gst">
   <select>
   <option>CGST 9% AND SGST 9% on service fee</option>
   <option>IGST 18% on service fee</option>
   </select> 
   <input type="text" value="54" name="tax">  // value get calculate on service fee is 54 (after javascipt programme)
   <input type="submit"  name="submit">

   </form>

   <?php

    $ctax= $_POST['tax'];  
    $ctax2= $ctax/2;  
    $ctax3= $ctax/2;
    sql_query= "INSERT INTO VISAINVC(cgst9%,sgst9%) VALUES('$ctax2','$ctax3')"

   ?>
```

the post value should get divided and insert into mysql visainvc table i.e

- `table column -> CGST 9% = 27  (50% of 54 - 18% ON SERVICE FEE i.e 300 )`
- `table column -> SGST 9% = 27  (50% of 54 - 18% ON SERVICE FEE i.e 300 )`

Comment: Hi, Welcome to DBA stack exchange. Would you please provide more information.

Comment: Above example is working exactly as documented. Even the string ('sql_query') does get a value of "INSERT INTO ….", but how should PHP know that you want this string used as a command for the database? Which database? You do no have any reference to a database in your code..    ==> more info needed

Comment: This is a PHP coding question - not a dba one and it belongs on StackOverflow! Always try first with the MySQL client (called `mysql`) and if you have a problem there, then it's a database issue. If you can get it to work on the MySQL client but not with PHP, then it's a programming issue. There are a few articles on how to ask questions here on my profile. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: first change your column name `cgst9%`,`sgst9%` to `cgst` & `sgst` and put extra information into comment section. other thing is show your column data_type is it (int OR varchar)?

Comment: "should" ...ok. So presumably it doesn't. What goes wrong when you try? Do you get an error? As far as I can see, all you've done here is create a string containing a SQL query. You never execute that query. Have you read any documentation / tutorials relating to using PHP to connect to a SQL database and run queries? If not then now would be a great time to do so. until you do that your code is not much use. Your `<select` is also missing a "name" attribute so the selected option will never be submitted to the server even though it appears to be important in deciding how to do the calculation

Answer (score 0):

first change your column name cgst9%,sgst9% to cgst & sgst and put extra information into comment section. other thing is insert value according to column data_type is it (int OR varchar).

```
<form>
  Service fee :
  <input type="text" value="300" name="invoiceValue" required>

  <select name="taxType" required>
    <option>Select Tax Type</option>
    <option value='1'>CGST 9% AND SGST 9% on service fee</option>
    <option value='2'>IGST 18% on service fee</option>
  </select> 

  <input type="submit"  name="submit">

</form>

<?php
  $invoiceValue = $_POST['invoiceValue'];
  $ctax= $_POST['taxType'];

  $sql_query = '';

  if($ctax == 1):
    $cgst = ($invoiceValue*9)/100;
    $sgst = ($invoiceValue*9)/100;
    $sql_query= "INSERT INTO `VISAINVC` (cgst,sgst) VALUES ($cgst, $sgst);";
  else if($ctax == 2):
    $igst = ($invoiceValue*18)/100;
    $sql_query= "INSERT INTO `VISAINVC` (igst) VALUES ($igst);";
  endif;

?>
```

Comment: note that this still won't actually execute the query

Comment: One of the things we can do here Pushpendra is to notify folks when they have a security problem. There is a SQL injection vulnerability in this code, and it is worth noting that, so the question author knows it needs to be fixed.

Comment: thnx pushpendra kumar ji and halfer :) for your valuable support.... GBU